# NameError: Python name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined How To Fix?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my website and the images wont load because I am having this error
***this is causing my images not to load on my website any help is appreciated thank you!***

```
2020-10-09T18:19:09.937117+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/mysite/settings.py", line 20, in <module>
2020-10-09T18:19:09.937117+00:00 app[web.1]: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
2020-10-09T18:19:09.937126+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined
```

my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os


from pathlib import Path


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'a49c&2is^-d$y8ycdycbenh*@dm3$3phszrs_72c*fh-ti1449'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False # remember to change to false

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['anim3-domain.herokuapp.com']
# 'https://anime-domain.herokuapp.com/'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/



STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

am i missing something? could you explain how I can fix it Thank You! I am not sure  if I am forgetting to import something or do I have to define the `BASE_DIR` if so how would I define it? and what do I need to import

my folders

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FBoT.png)

Comment: We have  no idea _where_ this error is happening.  Please post the full traceback error message.

Comment: yes I have added it refresh the page

Comment: The line on which the error happens is certainly not line 18 in the file you provided, so you certainly are running a different version of the file.

Comment: I updated the page again

Comment: You try to use `BASE_DIR` 3 lines before defining it, how can you expect it to be defined? Move the offending line below...

Comment: yes I placed them below and my iamges still arent showing on the website

Comment: Then this is a different problem and should be a different question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you are deploying on Heroku, you need to use something like `whitenoise` to serve your static files.

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Also: don't post your secret key on the internet.

Edited to add, it's worth also using something like https://github.com/pkrefta/django-on-heroku when deploying to Heroku.

Comment: I am already using whitenoise to serve my satic files

Comment: Now that you edited it haha it wasn't on there when I originally made the comment. Thanks for updating it.

Comment: @lillymosling were you able to solve it? Accessing Static files in deployment can be a frustrating issue but usually it's pretty simple to fix.

Comment: yes I did! but now I am having a new problem my images arent loading on my site

Comment: @lillymosling have you run `python manage.py collectstatic`? This is supposed to run when Heroku builds the program but I've found that isn't always completely true.

Answer (score -2):

you must try to import function os from python library to django on setting.py

Comment: They have already done that, as you can see in the code posted. Additionally, failing to do that wouldn't result in the error shown.